# MW2 LAN party PS3 - DLC maps

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I'm doing a MW2 PS3 LAN party and want to play matches on the DLC maps from the Stimulus and Resurgence packages.

If I buy the DLC on only one PS3 (the PS3 I use as the game host), will the other PS3 players be able to connect and play on the DLC maps?

Or would every console need to purchase the DLC in order to connect and play on these maps?

Answer (score 1):

I've never played LAN party, but it should be same system as online multiplayer; Every player should purchase DLC and download it on their own. The DLC maps are only downloaded when player purchased it from PS store (or whatever platform's store), and the maps are only visible when player downloaded the DLC (I mean, how can they see that when they does not have maps data in their storage?).

So, you and all of your friends should purchase the DLC, otherwise you guys can only play vanilla maps. As far as I'm aware, LAN party does not transfer map data.

Comment: Aah okay. That's unfortunate then. Do you know if they can be downloaded online and loaded onto the console via USB?

Comment: @user9506231 Uh, you mean like pirating it? If so then sorry, this site does not answer to [that kind of question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *site policies prohibit questions of the following types: ... Piracy, and support with pirated games ...*